# How i write file into home(In linux system)

Tags: livecode

I am trying to write file in my home folder(I am using Linux operating system) while i am writing the file into temp it's working

```
put shell("echo $HOME") into last1
```

The above code for getting home folder and I am place the path into variable last1

```
put the text of field "bash1" into URL "file:last1/dic.sh"
```

Here bash1 is an text field and it's contains some shell script i want to write into home directory

The below code is Works

```
put the text of field "bash1" into URL "file:/tmp/dic.sh"
```

How i rewrite my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your last1 variable is enclosed in quotes, it's getting treated as a literal string rather than a variable. The following would work:

`put field "bash1" into URL ("file:" & last1 & "/dic.sh")`

Note that you do not have to refer explicitly to the text property when putting texts from fields - you can do the above. Furthermore, if you're on Linux, you can just use the ~ shortcut to refer to the user's home directory:

`put field "bash1" into URL "file:~/dic.sh"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to "open" the file, write your stuff and "close" the file again.

try something like

```
put last1 & "/dic.sh" into myFile

open file myFile for write
write the text of field "bash1" to file myFile
close file myFile
```